# Flutter : How to create 'Favorite Item' list in another page

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created the ListView.builder that navigating every item (from local JSON) into detailed page of it's item, let's  we named it detailDoaPage.dart . Also, i've created another page to show the favorited item from detailDoaPage.dart, named favPage.dart . Unfortunately, I don't understand how to saved the favorited item from detailDoaPage.dart and show it in favPage.dart. Also, if we move to another page in my app, the doa.Fav that we have favorited (return doa.fav = true) will be back to false.

Here is the preview of my app:

[image]

The doa.dart (Doa class), doa.json, detailDoaPage.dart, and favPage.dart can be seen here : https://replit.com/join/ypfxwejy-nabilrei (Go to line 77 in detailDoaPage.dart to see the favorite icon). You can modify the code to tell me how to solve this problem.

I really thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is to use [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/). It will let you create a `favoritesList` which can be accessed from any widget. Take a look at the [hello world example](https://riverpod.dev/docs/getting_started#usage-example-hello-world) in their docs.

Comment: hmm can you tell me how can I implement it ??

Comment: It's simple really. Your implementation would be similar to this [counter example](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/blob/master/examples/counter/lib/main.dart). The only difference would be instead of dealing with an `int`, you would be dealing with a `List<String>` which would contain the id's of the favorite doas.

Comment: Hello, i want to ask you :) Now I'm using SharedPreferences in my favId (List of String variable to store favorited Id. Can I implemenet the riverpod with my SharedPreferences?

Comment: Sure. SharedPref is mostly used saving/loading data from disk. Riverpod makes it easy to share this data with any widget that needs it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67194040/flutter-how-to-use-riverpod-with-sharedpreference-and-liststring-variable-in I've ask here but no body answer my question hehe :)

Answer (score -1):

as it is a mock item I would create other JSON with it items of the other JSON and I add value to the property of name favorite with value true