# How can I get a changenotifier using a futureprovider with riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am using shared_preferences for my app and I have made a Settings class with helper methods.
As part of the Settings method I use Settings.create to generate my SharedPreferences.
It looks like this:

```
class Settings extends ChangeNotifier {
  final SharedPreferences prefs;

  Settings(this.prefs);

  static Future<Settings> create() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return Settings(prefs);
  }
  
  // ### Helper Methods ###
}
```

I have used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67194040/flutter-how-to-use-riverpod-with-sharedpreference-and-liststring-variable-in) to try a solution and have come up with this:

```
FutureProvider<Settings> createSettings = FutureProvider<Settings>((ref) {
  return Settings.create();
});

ChangeNotifierProvider<Settings> settingsProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<Settings> ((ref) {
  final settingsInstance = ref.watch(createSettings).maybeWhen(
        data: (value) => value,
        orElse: () => null,
      );
  return Settings(settingsInstance.prefs);
});
```

The problem I have now run into is that I get an Error because null is returned as long as the future has not completed.

I have hit a wall and am out of ideas. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, two options. Depending on the trade-offs you want to make.

## Options

### Option 1 (just wait)

In `main.dart` inside the `Future<void> main() async {}` function, just wait for the call to get shared prefs and then manually set the state in a your providers (using a state provider).

So that looks like:

(providers.dart)

```dart
final settingsProvider = StateProvider<Settings>((_) => defaultValue);

// ^ You can also make the above nullable if you don't have a reasonable default. But to be fair, this default will never be called if you're always setting it in main.
```

(main.dart)

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  final settings = await Settings.create();
  final container = ProviderContainer();
  container.read(settingsProvider.state).state = settings;
}
```

### Option 2 (same idea, just don't wait)

The same as the above code, but don't wait in main. Just don't wait. Here's the difference:

(main.dart)

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  final container = ProviderContainer();
  Settings.create().then((settings){
    container.read(settingsProvider.state).state = settings;
  });
  // The rest of your code...
  runApp();
}
```

## Overview / Comparison

Option #1 is more simple to work with, but you may not be okay with waiting if you want a fast startup. But I doubt that it matters. In that case, if you have reasonable defaults, then use option #2

For the code on using Riverpod in main(), please reference this Github issue comment:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/202#issuecomment-731585273

Comment: It makes reading / writing possible for the settings, but "notifylisteners" does not trigger a rebuild of the current page. What can I do about this?

Comment: You'll have to call notifyListeners, I think. See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/notifyListeners.html